# Invoke-Expression not passing a comma delimited list of strings to script as a single parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that is calling a batch script (running perl inside) which isn't parsing parameters correctly when called from my powershell script. The situation is as follows.

When calling my batch/perl script manually

```
test.cmd -tasks "Task A","Task B","Task C"
```

everything works fine and the parameter "Task A","Task B","Task C" is treated as one unit that gets passed into another executable.

But when calling using invoke-expression

```
$fullCommand = "cmd.exe /C C:\test\test.cmd -tasks  `"Task A`",`"Task B`",`"Task C`";
Invoke-Expression -Command $fullCommand;
```

The batch script thinks that each string is a separate parameter. In other words, "Task A" is the first parameter after -tasks, then "Task B", then "Task C", which the script doesn't recognize how to process.

I could get around this by passing in each task name individually (e.g. -Task "Task A" -Task "Task B" -Task "Task C"), but that would require me to have extra logic to parse these, put them into an array, then reform them into a string and pass back into another executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoke-Expression takes a powershell expression. If you want to run an executable, just use the & operator. e.g.

```
$exe = cmd.exe
$params = @("/C", "-tasks", '"Task A, "Task B", "Task C"') 
& $exe $params
```

Comment: This ended up working but I had issues with the variables being named $exe and $params. I ended up calling it like this.


& cmd.exe $parameters

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to accomplish this using single and double quoted strings.  Try:

```
iex 'cmd /c c:\test\test.cmd -tasks "Task A","Task B","Task C"'
```

One way to help work out these problems is to grab the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) and use the `echoargs.exe` util in place of the program you want to run e.g.:

```
8> iex 'cmd /c EchoArgs.exe -tasks "Task A","Task B","Task C"'
Arg 0 is <-tasks>
Arg 1 is <Task A>
Arg 2 is <Task B>
Arg 3 is <Task C>

Command line:
EchoArgs.exe  -tasks "Task A" "Task B" "Task C"
```

It will show you how your program is receiving the arguments from PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script exclude sub-folder and delete only files of root folder

```
foreach($a in $b=(Get-childItem "C:\test\" "*.*"| Where-Object{!$_.psiscontainer}).FullName)
{
   $c="cmd.exe /C del /f '$a'"
   Invoke-Expression  $c
}
```